# php cannot define variable

Tags: php, variables, post, get

for some reason i cant find my error why  i cant define my $id variable and paste it into my my_sqly query.
everything else is working fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my PHP "process" file (update.php)

```
    if (isset($_POST['button1'])) 
    { 
        $id = $_POST["id"];
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM member WHERE id = '".$id."'") or die("cannot execute the query");

    }
```

and my other file

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
        {
            $id = $row["id"];
            //echo '<form action="update.php" method="post">';
            echo '<table border="1">';
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td> '.$row["username"].'</td>';
                echo '<td> '.$row["password"].' </td>';
                echo '<form method="POST" action="update.php">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$_SESSION["return_url"].'" />';
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='hidden_id' value='$id' />";
                echo '<input type="submit" name="button1"  value="My Button">';
                echo '</form>';     
}
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a form element as a child of a tr element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using hidden_id as name for the input where you store $id from previous request.
So to access it, you need to do

```
$id = $_POST["hidden_id"];
```

For future reference, take a look at [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) as you are not sanitizing your user input.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
```

to

```
$id = $_POST["hidden_id"];
```

That is the name of your input field and not only "id"